# The reference of "son" in "Mettre son ambition non à se révolter, mais à servir" from André Gide

Tags: sens, pronoms

This passage is from La Porte étroite by André Gide.  The elision (marked by '...') is not mine, but part of the book.

> Cher Jérôme,
>        Je fonds de joie en te lisant. J’allais répondre à ta lettre d’Orvieto, quand, à la fois, celle de Pérouse et celle d’Assise sont arrivées. Ma pensée se fait voyageuse ; mon corps seul fait semblant d’être ici ; en vérité, je suis avec toi sur les blanches routes d’Ombrie ; avec toi je pars au matin, regarde avec un œil tout neuf l’aurore… Sur la terrasse de Cortone m’appelais-tu vraiment ? je t’entendais… On avait terriblement soif dans la montagne au-dessus d’Assise ! mais que le verre d’eau du Franciscain m’a paru bon ! Ô mon ami ! je regarde à travers toi chaque chose. Que j’aime ce que tu m’écris à propos de saint François ! Oui, n’est-ce pas, ce qu’il **faut** chercher c’est une exaltation et non point une émancipation de la pensée. Celle-ci ne va pas sans un orgueil abominable. Mettre **son** ambition non à se révolter, mais à servir…
>        Les nouvelles de Nîmes sont si bonnes qu’il me paraît que Dieu me permet de m’abandonner à la joie. La seule ombre de cet été, c’est l’état de mon pauvre père ; malgré mes soins il reste triste, ou plutôt il retrouve sa tristesse dès l’instant que je l’abandonne à lui-même et il s’en laisse toujours moins aisément tirer. Toute la joie de la nature parle autour de nous une langue qui lui devient étrangère ; il ne fait même plus effort pour l’entendre. – Miss Ashburton va bien. Je leur lis à tous deux tes lettres ; chacune nous donne de quoi causer pour trois jours ; alors arrive une lettre nouvelle…

I am trying to figure out where *son* as highlighted above comes from.

Could it be this?

1. The fragment *Mettre son ambition non à se révolter, mais à servir...* has an implicit *falloir* so that, as completed, it should read:

> Il faut mettre son ambition non à se révolter, mais à servir...

2. It was permissible to suppress *faut* because there was another instance just above (as highlighted).
3. The implicit subject of <strike>*faut*</strike> *mettre* is *on*.
4. The possessive for *on* is *son*.

Please let me know if my guess is correct.  If it is wrong, please tell me how I could account for *son*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does refer to "*on*".

"*Il faut* " is enough to make "*on*" the subject of the following verbs, you can very well start another sentence and keep it as your subject. Note that other things can make "*on*" the subject (*c'est important...*, *ça serait bien...*, etc.)

The possessives for "*on*" are "*son/sa/ses*". The tonic (I think that's the word) is "*soi*", as in: "*Il faut tout faire soi-même, ici !*"

Comment: Thank you. I amended the question as per your answer:  *on* = the implicit subject of *mettre* rather than *faut*.